# How can I effectively downgrade python in Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, archlinux

I wanted to use turicreate library which doesn't support python 3.8 yet. So tried downgrading python to 3.7 using

```
downgrade python
```

But now I cant use pip. Even a simple command using pip like,

```
pip --version
```

gives me an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

I have already tried downgrading pip to 19.0.3.
Also tried uninstalling and reinstalling both packages.

What can I possibly do? I use Arch Linux btw.

Comment: Have a look a [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and optionally [pyenv-autoenv](https://github.com/andersoncardoso/pyenv-autoenv). You just have to `cd` into your project directory to activate the venv, in case you need a Python version that is not installed, pyenv does it for you.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer this seems to be a good solution, but the python version is not changing for me on using this.

Comment: You might want edit your question, about what you did (Did you install pyenv correctly and restarted the Shell, ... ?)

Comment: I did a little research and I can make it work by editing `~/.bash_profile` a bit. I also have to delete `./.python-version` everytime I want to switch versions. But the main problem is I want to use this python version in jupyter notebook. `pyenv` seems to change the python version only for that particular terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of downgrading python for the whole OS, may be you should try using a downgraded python version for just your project.

Try using a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) and use it to create a dev environment with python 3.7.

Comment: I am not that familiar with virtaulenv but I believe this is whats expected. 
    `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.7 <path>`
But python3.7 wont be in /usr/bin/ as the currently installed version is python 3.8

Comment: You can install the python version you're interested in from source - to the location that you want and then point your virtual environment towards it.

[This might help](https://software.rc.fas.harvard.edu/training/scraping/install/source.html)